# problem with red5phone unable to connect

Tags: linux, sip, red5

i'm looking at red5 and red5phone to make it works.

i am getting an error

netconnection: Status: 1 rtmpconnection #phone _onStatus NetConnection.Connect.Failed netconnection: Status: 0 connection failed to rtmp://localhost/sip : connection failed

is somebody have some experience with that????

Regards, Sunil

Comment: Can you provide us with some diagnostics that you've done, and the outcomes?

Answer (score 0):

I know a little bit about sip, it almost looks like it's trying to connect to itself are you sure you have your sip server entered in correctly?

Comment: hey thanks for reply, now sip phone is connected but i am able to make a call from it this error :                                                               callState: onUaCallClosed 
WARNING: phoneLib.lzx:84: reference to undefined variable 'incomingNetStream' 
callState: onUaCallClosed

Comment: Don't know that's not a terribly useful error to me. What does Red5 say?